# Why doesn't this simple program print a thing?

Tags: c

I have written a simple program that is supposed to add 1 and 53, and return 54. But apparantly it does nothing. No error, just nothing.

The file is saved as `firstEx.c`, I compiled and run like this

```
$ gcc -o firstEx firstEx.c
$ ./firstEx
```

All goes fine, except I see no output.
Can anyone help? (I'm totally new to C.)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
  int var1, var2;
  var1 = 1; 
  var2 = 53;
  void add_two_numbers (int var1, int var2);
  return 0;
}

void add_two_numbers (int a, int b) 
{ 
  int c;
  c = a + b; 
  printf ("%d\n", c); 
}
```

Comment: Im working on IOS, if that matters

Comment: you also need a forward declaration

Comment: Well...there seems to be a major lack of knowledge for me.  You better start over with a step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 11):

The line

```
void add_two_numbers (int var1, int var2);
```

is a function prototype, *not* a call to said function. It's *unusual* to see it in the middle of a function but it's certainly valid, since it's just a style of declaration as per the standard (`ISO C11 6.7`).

To actually *call* the function, you have to use something like:

```
add_two_numbers (var1, var2);
```

You should also ensure the function prototype is within scope when you call it, by either providing a prototype beforehand or simply defining the function before you call it. I'd start with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add_two_numbers (int a, int b) {
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    printf ("%d\n", c);
}

int main (void) {
    int var1, var2;
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 53;
    add_two_numbers (var1, var2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you wanted to *keep* the order of functions the same, a prototype approach could be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add_two_numbers (int, int);

int main (void) {
    int var1, var2;
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 53;
    add_two_numbers (var1, var2);
    return 0;
}

void add_two_numbers (int a, int b) {
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    printf ("%d\n", c);
}
```

---

A couple of other things just to keep you thinking:

- You should name your functions based on intent. Most code cutters will expect a function called `add_two_numbers` to add the numbers and *return* the result, rather than print out the sum. Perhaps a better name would have been `print_sum_of_two_numbers`.
- It's not necessary to always use variables, unless you're intending the value to vary :-) The entire `add_two_numbers` function could be whittled down to the single line `printf ("%d", a + b);`.
- Similarly, the first four lines of `main` could be reduced to `add_two_numbers (1, 53);`.
- As of C99, you no longer have to explicitly return zero from `main`, it will return zero "automagically" if you drop out the bottom. Some people may still prefer to be explicit, and quite a few oldies like myself will put it in just from force of habit, but it's no longer necessary.

With all those changes, you can end up with the far more succinct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_sum_of_two_numbers (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d\n", a + b);
}

int main (void) {
    print_sum_of_two_numbers (1, 53);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, but could you please tell me how I can correctly provide a prototype for the add_two_numbers function in my code?

Comment: According to your explanation, I could have used a prototype definition instead of interchanging the main function with the add_two_numbers function. Right? But what is the correct way to define the f unction?

Comment: Got it now!  Thank you for your clear and simple explanation.

Comment: "As of C99, you no longer have to explicitly return zero from main, it will return zero "automagically" if you drop out the bottom." Just because it is now valid, it doesn't mean that it is good practice or should be used. To rewrite programs to remove `return 0` just because it is now allowed is nonsense. I think no return needed from main was added to save some old, crappy programs that previously had UB, rather than to give programmers a new feature to use.

Comment: @Lundin, I'm in no sense advocating rewriting working programs to remove the `return 0` at the end of `main`, especially since it will have no functional benefit. I just no longer use it myself because it's not needed (I no longer target C on embedded, I have at least C99 everywhere else) although I often catch myself typing it in before I remember :-) In any case, the *reason* for it is irrelevant, it's in there now, so we can use it freely.